# Writing logs into Excel file using Serilog for .NET

Tags: c#, wpf, logging, serilog

I have implemented `logging` in my WPF application using `Serilog`. I want the output to be generated to be in `Excel` format.
I want the `excel` file to have these `column headers` as mentioned below so that I can `sort` by applying `filters`.

```
date time| logtype |environment| app build version | test case description | status
```

A sample `output` should look like below

```
date time       | logtype    |environment| app build version| test case description | status
02-04-2020 4:30 | Test Reults|aBC06      |2.0.150           | Loading Views         | Success
```

I have the following `logging` configuration

```
 public class LoggerFactory : ILoggerFactory
    {
        public Serilog.Core.Logger Create()
        {
            var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .ReadFrom.AppSettings()
                .CreateLogger();
            return logger;
        }
    }
```

The `AppSettings` has this configuration

```
<add key="serilog:using:Seq" value="Serilog.Sinks.Seq" />
    <add key="serilog:using:RollingFile" value="Serilog.Sinks.RollingFile" />
    <add key="serilog:write-to:RollingFile.pathFormat" value="C:\Dev\Logs\abc-ui-automation-{Date}.txt" />
    <add key="serilog:write-to:RollingFile.retainedFileCountLimit" value="10" />
    <add key="serilog:write-to:Seq.serverUrl" value="http://localhost:5341" />
```

Currently, the `logger` is writing in a `txt` file without the format mentioned above. How do I ensure that I achieve the task mentioned above?

Comment: When you say "Excel format", do you mean an actual OOXML Excel file (`*.xlsx`) - or a CSV file? Because a CSV file is **not** an "Excel file" - and you cannot "append" to an OOXML Excel file because it's a set of separate XML files contained in a PKZIP container. Unlike the original OLE-based Office 97-2003 file formats which did support incremental writes (which were horribly complicated to use and understand), the post-Office 2007 OOXML types do not.

Comment: @Dai anything that helps me writing in the format mentioned above. The file would be open till the logging goes on and the entries have to be updated accordingly

Comment: "writing in the format mentioned above" - you've missed my question. I'm asking you to name **which specific format** - are you talking about CSV or OOXML?

Comment: OOXML I believe.

Comment: @Dai I am even oka to open a csv file using excel but the logging should be in the format mentioned and the column headers should be there. Need a detailed implementation. Very new to this

Answer (score 3):

Simplest solution would be to log data as CSV and open it with excel afterwards. Therefore you could simply implement your own version of an [ITextFormatter](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/blob/dev/src/Serilog/Formatting/ITextFormatter.cs). Check the default implementations like [RawFormatter](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/blob/dev/src/Serilog/Formatting/Raw/RawFormatter.cs) to see how.

You only need to write your own implementation like

```
public void Format(LogEvent logEvent, TextWriter output)
{
    output.write(logEvent.Timestamp.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy H:mm");
    output.write(";");
    output.write(logEvent.Level);
    output.write(";");
    output.write(logEvent.Properties["KEY"]);
    output.write(";");
    //...
    output.WriteLine();
}
```

To write the header, you could make use of the [Serilog.Sinks.File.Header](https://github.com/cocowalla/serilog-sinks-file-header) package. Basically it could be done like

```
Func<string> headerFactory = () => "date time;logtype;...";

Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .WriteTo.File(new YourCsvFormatter(), "log.csv", hooks: new HeaderWriter(headerFactory))
    .CreateLogger();
```

Comment: How to have those columns as headers?

Comment: What about the configuration in App.Config? Do I need to make changes there too?

Comment: No, this should be done if you are doing it not in code.

Comment: I am trying to implement what you have suggested. Really new to this. Can you explain the Format Method?

Comment: The method just writes some strings to your logfile. It gets called for every log entry. So here you are able to define how to print a line in the file by adding strings.

Comment: what should be an ideal ```YourCsvFormatter``` in my case?

Comment: So the ";" would ensure that the next entry goes into the next cell? I need to write data columnwise.

Comment: Yes. One row for each method call.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210821/discussion-between-apoorv-and-fruchtzwerg).

Comment: ```logEvent.Properties["KEY"]``` what should be the key here keeping in mind my header

Comment: Why not using a breakpoint to check the values available as key? I think you should starting with a basic C# tutorial before digging deeper.

Comment: I will take care of this. Thanks for your suggestion

Comment: tried this sample. ```;``` had to be replaced with ```,``` . The column header is being written now